# How to set background for several views in gridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm writing an  application which has a gridView. This gridview consists of several imageViews. I'm able to set the background for a clicked item. But I need to set the background for several items.

The following code didn't help me:

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        for(int eachCoordinate: coordinates){
            gridview.getChildAt(eacheachCoordinate).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.point);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, that code doesn't look right. Anyway, what are coordinates and how do you choose them?

Comment: Coordinates are the item positions which background have to be replaced. I get them before using here.

Comment: you are probably doing it wrong. also why would you want to change the background of every item in your gridview whenever one of them gets clicked?

Comment: Situation is the following: I have gridview with set backgrounds. I need to replace background not in all items, but in items which positions are in Coordinate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I should change adapter resources and then invalidate gridView.